does siesta type NOSE use a Nose-Hoover thermostat or just Nose thermostat?
I am confused because I assumed it uses the Nose-Hoover thermostat as it is the further developed method from Nose but often it is referred to as only the Nose thermostat. I want to understand the working mechanism of the Thermostat in SIESTA more deeply so an answer would be great.

This presentation by one of the Siesta developers mentions the Nosé-Hoover thermostat. The two formalisms are ultimately similar, but Hoover's approach is physically more intuitive (by virtue of introducing a friction term) so it has become the default implementation.
Of course, reaching out to the developers is always an option to be sure.
